# Is there anyway to programmatically unminimize a stage in javafx

Tags: windows, javafx-2

The question is pretty simple, on a stage in javafx 2.2 where maximization is not an option (by taking off the control from the menu bar) but it needs to be allowed to be minimized, is it possible to, in code, un-minimize the stage?

things I've tried (and I have access to the static stage):

```
stage.show();
stage.requestFocus();
stage.toFront();
stage.getScene().getWindow().requestFocus();
```

Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        stage.show();
        stage.requestFocus();
        stage.toFront();
        stage.getScene().getWindow().requestFocus();
    }
});

none had any effect. I tried googling around, and only came up with solutions that make it so the user isn't allowed to minimize in the first place, which really isn't an option for me.

Anyway, if anyone has a clever idea, I'm all ears. The program DOES use some jni with c, so native calls aren't out of the question, but I'm going to consider that to really be a last-resort.

Worth noting, this is on javafx 2.2 jdk 7_bu52 Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe i missunderstood something but can't you use stage method

```
setIconified(boolean value)
```

Comment: If I could upvote this more times, I would! +1 for a one-line fix to my problem. I have no idea how I missed that method. haha Thanks!

Comment: I might add that using the OP options with @Inge answer, it works for `stage.setIconified(false);` and `stage.toFront();`. Hope it helps !